# setTranslationX and setTranslationY make wrong position of Button in Android. Why?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I have two buttons:1 and 2. The first button will be located in center of layout and the second will translation using `setTranslationX and setTranslationY` The code is for that is

```
    btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    setRotateButton(btn1,2,1);
    btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    setRotateButton(btn2,2,2);
```

where `setRotateButton` is

```
public void setRotateButton(Button btn,int numViews,int index)
{
    //Locate button in center
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(130, 130);
    lp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
    btn.setLayoutParams(lp);
    //Translation
    if (index>1) //To avoid first case
    {
        float angleDeg = index * 360.0f / numViews - 90.0f;
        float angleRad = (float)(angleDeg * Math.PI / 180.0f);
        btn.setTranslationX(400 * (float)Math.cos(angleRad));
        btn.setTranslationY(400 * (float)Math.sin(angleRad));
    }    
}
```

I found an issue that when I use `setTranslationX,setTranslationY`, the location of the button 2 can translate to another location but I got a wrong number for the location of button 2. It always returns the same value. To check it. I using `onTouch` method (mainFrame is a FrameLayout where contains these two buttons). Could you help me to fix the function in  `setRotateButton`? Thank you so much.

```
 @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();

        mainFrame.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                int x = (int) event.getX();
                int y = (int) event.getY();

                for (int i = 0; i < mainFrame.getChildCount(); i++) {
                    View current = mainFrame.getChildAt(i);
                    if (current instanceof Button) {
                        Button b = (Button) current;
                        Log.d("TAG","Btn pos:"+String.valueOf(b.getLeft())+";"+String.valueOf(b.getRight())+";"+String.valueOf(b.getTop())+";"+String.valueOf(b.getBottom()));
                        if (!isPointWithin(x, y, b.getLeft(), b.getRight(), b.getTop(),
                                b.getBottom())) {
                            b.getBackground().setState(defaultStates);
                            b.getBackground().setAlpha(255);

                        }

                        if (isPointWithin(x, y, b.getLeft(), b.getRight(), b.getTop(),
                                b.getBottom())) {
                            b.getBackground().setState(STATE_PRESSED);
                            b.getBackground().setAlpha(150);
                            b.performClick();

                            if (b != mLastButton) {
                                mLastButton = b;

                            }
                        }

                    }

                }
                return true;
            }

        });

    }
```

This is log result

When I move the finger inside button 1, and move to outside it

```
09-15 00:15:50.981 20547-20547/com.example.circlelayout D/TAG: Btn pos:0;150;300;450
09-15 00:01:40.891 20547-20547/com.example.circlelayout D/TAG: Btn pos:397;527;485;615
```

When I move the finger inside button 2 and move outside . They are same value

```
09-15 00:01:40.891 20547-20547/com.example.circlelayout D/TAG: Btn pos:397;527;485;615
09-15 00:01:40.891 20547-20547/com.example.circlelayout D/TAG: Btn pos:397;527;485;615
09-15 00:01:40.891 20547-20547/com.example.circlelayout D/TAG: Btn pos:397;527;485;615
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Methods like `getLeft()` don't take into account that the `View` was translated. They always return the initial value which was calculated during the layout process.

So you need instead to use `getX()` and `getY()` and calculate the new bottom and right corners. For example:

```
int bX = b.getX();
intbY = b.getY();

if (isPointWithin(x, y,
             bX, bX + (b.getRight() - b.getLeft()),
             bY, bY + (b.getBottom() - b.getTop()) ) )
{
     b.getBackground().setState(STATE_PRESSED);
     b.getBackground().setAlpha(150);
     b.performClick();

     if (b != mLastButton) {
         mLastButton = b;
     }
}
```